# How to implement 'fields' paramenter for 'get' in REST API in server side

Tags: api, rest, get, field

I would like to know, how to implement 'fields' paramenter for 'get' in REST API in server side.

for eg: http://example.com/user?fields=firstName,lastName

Here I have to get the firstName and lastName from users table.

Should I name the table fields like firstName, lastName and select all colums in the fields list or use aliases and find the column names from the aliases and select them?

I also have some secure fields like passwordHash, which should not be requested. So I need to put some restrictions also. So in server side I have to manually check for these fields (also the * or users.* etc). But these fields should be allowed for update.

Can anybody tell me the best approach for implementing this in terms of security, performance and clean code?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you have an usual web application, you could use a request without any query parameters for all requests and show/hide the columns on the client. You may return too much data on the first request but you don't need additional requests because all the data is there already.

Edit: Of course you should not include "passwordHash" or other sensible data in your query.

Comment: You definitely should never ever expose secure fields like "passwordHash" to REST API. And I agree with @enigma969 that `fields` query parameter is not needed. If you have field with large amount of data and you don't want to fetch it with every request just use separate path for it like `/user/{id}/field_with_large_amount_of_data` or `/large_user_data_field/{userId}`

Comment: What if I have 100 columns and each column contains medium size data?